# EF Core - Get select query results while migrating

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core and the Users table had a plain-text password column. Adding a new EncryptedPassword column instead to replace this. I cannot insert encrypted passwords by running a plain UPDATE script in the migration file since the encryption process is done in the code. Is there a way to read data from the migration methods, something like,

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
        name: "EncryptedPassword",
        table: "Users",
        type: "nvarchar(200)",
        nullable: true);

    var rows = migrationBuilder.Sql("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE EncryptedPassword = NULL");

    foreach(var row in rows)
    {
        string encPwd = PasswordManage.Encrypt(row.Password);
        migrationBuilder.Sql($"UPDATE Users SET EncryptedPassword = '{encPwd}' WHERE Id = '{row.Id}'")
    }
}
```

What will be the best approach to insert the encrypted passwords for the existing users?

### Update

I now understand that this is not the way to go. I was able to read data using context. But this means that the scripts generated for migration will only work for the current database that is used to generate it. So it would be useless for any other database.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are translated to Sql code upon migration.
There is a method called migrationBuilder.Sql() and has the option to be executed inside the transaction so if the sql fails, transaction is rolled back.

You could use a MERGE statement to achieve this.

1. Compute all the password conversions and store them in a temporary table. Can work too with variable table

```
CREATE TABLE [Temp].[Table] ([Password] nvarchar(8000), [Enc] nvarchar(8000));

INSERT INTO [Temp].[Table] ([Password], [Enc]) VALUES {CommaSeparatedValues}
```

2. Perform merge operations

```
MERGE INTO [Users] AS U USING [Temp].[Table] AS T 
   ON U.[Password] = T.[Password] 
   WHEN MATCHED AND U.[EncryptedPassword] IS NULL 
     THEN UPDATE SET U.[EncryptedPassword] = T.[Enc];
```

3. Delete the temp table

```
DROP TABLE [Temp].[Table]
```

Additionally, you can inject the ApplicationDbContext or create a new one inside the migration, so you can build the comma separated values inside the Up method.

```
public partial class PasswordEncryptMigration : Migration
{
   protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
   {
      using AppDbContext _context = new (ConnectionString);

      /* Query the server */
      var a = _context.Users
         .Where(x => x.EncryptedPassword == null)
         .Select(x => x.Password)
         .ToList();
      
      /* Get the encrypted password */
      var csv = a.Select(x => $"('{x}', '{PasswordManage.Encrypt(x)}')")
         .Aggregate((a,b) => a + ", " + b);

      migrationBuilder.Sql('{SQL from step 1 with csv added}');

      migrationBuilder.sql('Step 2 ...')

      //...
   }
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations